# .NET MVC user details in Controller CTOR

Tags: asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I would like to find a way to use custom User provider within a controllers ctor in order to not have to get the user on every method (dirty)..

This is what is in my ctor but keeps returning null?

```
Resource oResource;
public EntityController()
{
    try
    {
        DataEntities oEntities = new DataEntities();
        oResource = oEntities.Resources.Where(c => c.user == User.Identity.Name).First();
    }
    catch
    {
        oResource = new Resource();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the `Controller.Initialize()` method and put your code in there. The controller's context isn't available in the constructor.

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{       
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    // your code here
}
```

If you need the user's entity on every action, then push the behavior into a base class that your controllers inherit from.